# Where is `Google Speech API Key`?

Tags: api, speech-recognition, chromium, voice-recognition, google-speech-api

I was refering to [this link](http://mikepultz.com/2013/07/google-speech-api-full-duplex-php-version/) where it discuss about the Google Speech engine. It says that I have to get an API Key from google, to use the google speech engine they are discussing. In the link posted, they have shown an image of activating the Speech API Key.

However when I went to the [API Site](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) I can't find anything about `Speech API`.

Is there no more API keys for Speech API? Or else no need to use them? It is worth to understand that this speech API allows uploading `flac` files, which is quite different from others.

Answer (score 5):

To get an API key, go to [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), create a project, then go to Library on the right, find the Speech API, and enable it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a PDF guide with screenshots that shows how to set this up in 2022:

https://www.blackwiredesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/Creating-a-Google-Cloud-Text-to-Speech-API-Key.pdf

In short, you need to:

1. Enable the Cloud Text-to-Speech API - [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/texttospeech.googleapis.com)
2. Create the API Key credential to it - [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)

Comment: oh no! its a 404 for the pdf!

Answer (score -1):

Have you heard about this Web Speech API:

https://www.google.com/intl/pt/chrome/demos/speech.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API

I don't know if this API solves your problem, but im working with this and it's quite nice!

Comment: So you need an API Key?

Comment: No, you dont need anything to use this API.

Comment: Can you transcribe long audio with web speech api where a user can upload a file and get the transcription?

Comment: While this can help solve the problem the person asking the question is having, I don't think it actually answers the question.